# pixel-precise positioning of line mesh on top of image data with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to precisely overlay a mesh of 1-pixel wide lines on top of an image grid as displayed by the python library matplotlib.

Unfortunately, I seem to be unable to have enough fine control over the result to achieve proper alignment of the line mesh with the data grid, as the code below shows. The results seems to always be close but not quite exactly right.

I have tried using both the `imshow` and `pcolormesh` functions, and encountered problems with both approaches.

imshow approach:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

size = 60
border = 5

#create test data for image and ticks location
im = np.zeros(shape=(size,size),dtype=np.float32)
ticks = np.arange(size)+0.5

#create test checkerboard pattern outside of border area
for index in range(size-2*border):
    im[border+index,border:-border] += index % 2
for index in range(size-2*border):
    im[border:-border,index+border] -= index % 2
im = np.abs(im)

#display image with imshow
plt.imshow(im, interpolation='nearest', cmap='binary', vmin=0, vmax=1)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels([])
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
#sometimes line is off by 1 pixel
plt.show()
```

I would expect the line mesh of red lines to overlay precisely the checkerboard pattern of the data grid, but they are off by one pixel.

This zoomed image show the results and the offset is easily visible:

[image: red_mesh_offset_by_one_pixel]

I also tried using pcolormesh and edgecolor (using same data as above):

```py
plt.pcolormesh(im, cmap='binary', vmin=0, vmax=1, edgecolors='r', linewidth=0.005)
plt.show()
```

Here the red line mesh aligns better, but the line width is not consistent, sometimes is 1-pixel wide, sometimes 2-pixel wide, as shown in this image: 
[image: red_mesh_inconsistent_line_width]

Here, ideally, I would like to always get a 1-pixel wide line.
It is possible to play around with the linewidth parameter, but if I make it too small, then the lines start to have 0-pixel width and they disappear altogether, and also I am not quite understanding what is the unit of linewidth.

In conclusion, I would appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve consistency in both positioning (red line mesh without offset from black and white checkerboard) and line width (always exactly 1-pixel wide on screen).

Comment: Grids are snapped to the nearest pixel but if one overlaps a pixel boundary it’ll sometimes get made twice as wide.  If you really want to poke pixels like this can I suggest that matplotlib is not the best tool?  Pillow will allow you to read and write image files into numpy arrays and you can change the RGBA values directly there.  Matplotlib works much better when it’s assumed the resolution is high enough that anti aliasing works to make a pleasing representation on screen or in a figure.

Comment: Hallo @Jody , the usage case is an interactive display of wafermaps with thousands of dies (also allowing such functionality as zoom in etc.) and we also display other stuff like histogram distribution of values - therefore a matplotlib solution would be a lot more desirable and simple (if at all possible). While the problem is only visible at the most zoomed out level, this is where you can see the entire wafer and therefore most useful.

Comment: I think there are issues for both these on GitHub. You could dig those up and comment there.  But basically imshow and the ticks/grids snap to the nearest pixel and pcolormesh uses antialiasing.  In addition there is something wrong w imshow and how it translates from data to image pixels.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12934 describes this issue and most of the other similar issues are linked.  I've stopped worrying about this because I think that matplotlib will soonish move over to using cairo as the main rasterization backend, and it has fixed a lot of these issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well, I guess I'll answer my own question. This is based on trial and error, so I am not sure if it is universally valid, but I hope the information may be useful for someone.

I was able to consistently plot the `pcolormesh` grid with width of exactly 1 pixels using the code below, where `my_dpi` needs to be set exactly to the dpi resolution of the display screen
and `imsize_pixel_x` and `imsize_pixel_y` are the desired size of the plot window.

```py
my_dpi = 96.0
imsize_pixel_x = 800
imsize_pixel_y = 600

plt.figure(figsize=(imsize_pixel_x/my_dpi, imsize_pixel_y/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)
plt.pcolormesh(im, cmap='binary', vmin=0, vmax=1, edgecolors='r', linewidth=my_dpi/(1024*32))

plt.show()
```